# Unit test in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

The below file is *test.js* where I am trying to write a unit test for a product function.

Since I am a beginner, I am not using any frameworks and am just defining my own framework. But I get "Uncaught TypeError: Math is not a function".

```
function testFunction() {
    var testobj = new Math();
    var actual = testobj.myFunction(1, 1);
    isequal(actual,1);
    var passlist = [];
    var faillist = [];

    function isequal(actual, expected) {
        if(actual === expected) {
            console.write("test passed");
            passlist.push("test passed");
        }
        else{
            console.write("test passed");
            faillist.push("test failed");
        }
        actual = testobj.myFunction(1, 0);
        isequal(actual, 0);

        if(actual === expected) {
            console.write("test passed");
            passlist.push("test passed");
        }
        else{
            console.write("test passed");
            faillist.push("test failed");
        }

    }
    document.getElementById("testvalue").innerHTML = passlist;
}
```

Here is the *main.js* file where two numbers from user input are multiplied and the output is returned to user. Since I am beginner in writing unit test, I would like to use my own framework.

```
function myFunction(num1,num2) {
    var y = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var x = y * z;
    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: `var testobj = new Math();` what are you trying to do with this line? this causes the error

Comment: Did you try to make a function called `Math` and forget there is a built in objected Math?

Comment: I was trying like this var testobj;
var actual = testobj.myFunction(1,1);..... But got error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myFunction' of undefined" and hence I defined the type of object as math

Comment: Your function is not a method. So call it like a function `var actual = myFunction(1,1)`